# How to find all tables whose name ends with a certain suffix in the Firebird system tables

Tags: firebird

I'm trying to run the following query to get a list of table names that match a pattern. I have tables in my db that has names ends with T, but the following query doesn't work. It doesn't return me any table names. If I get rid of T, only leave `%` in the quotes, it gives me all the table names in the db.

```sql
select rdb$relation_name 
from rdb$relations 
where rdb$relation_name like '%T';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the datatype of `RDB$RELATION_NAME` is `CHAR(31)` (`CHAR(63)` in Firebird 4), which means it is padded with spaces. Comparisons with `LIKE` do not ignore trailing spaces, contrary to equality comparison which does ignore trailing spaces.

For correct comparisons you can [`TRIM`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-trim) the trailing spaces from the value:

```sql
where trim(trailing from rdb$relation_name) like '%T'
```

or use a SQL regular expression with [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-predicates.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto):

```sql
where rdb$relation_name similar to '%T *'
```

Which is similar to the like, but specifies it is followed by zero or more spaces.

Comment: I wonder why the `char` data type was chosen for that. Isn't that a huge waste of space if the database contains many tables? (and columns, indexes, constraints etc - I assume they all use `char`  rather than `varchar`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe that decision is rather historical somewhere in the beginning of the 1980s, but storage-wise there is not much difference between VARCHAR and CHAR (on-disk both are padded, VARCHAR with 0x00 (NUL) and CHAR with 0x20 (space)), and a simple RLE encoding reduces the effects of padding. IIRC, VARCHAR even has a little bit more overhead because it also uses two bytes for the actual length.

Comment: Also, history of GDS/Interbase/Firebird predates SQL. For comparison, DBF-files do space-pad C-type fields too. Guess for much smaller disks then it made good tradeoff to trim-on-loading. I believe I had some documentation of FB's ancestral GDML/QLI language, but can not find it now. I am not sure GDML (or rather GDEF) even had variable-length text concept

Comment: Upd. Found Interbase 3 documentation (the one, mentioning VMS and Apollo, but not DOS-Windows-OS/2, just to feel the age), and `ddl_syntax.pdf` in `field-attributes` chapter has both `char[n]` and `varying[n]` data types.